# Matplotlib fetching irregular shape

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, networkx

This displays a node which is a figure using `networkx` and `matplotlib`:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()
n = "%%%%% \n% % % \n%%%%%"
print n
G.add_node(n)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

`print n` displays:

```
%%%%% 
% % % 
%%%%%
```

`plt.show()` displays:

```
%%%%% 
 %%% 
%%%%%
```

The data is very large so i can't edit n and rearrange it for desired output.
How can I code such that both the shapes are equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set n again with a differently formated string:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()
n = "%%%%% \n% % % \n%%%%%"
print n
n = n.replace(" ", "   ")
G.add_node(n)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

And you will get the following figure [image]
and output:

```
%%%%% 
% % % 
%%%%%
```

Or is there any reason that you did not specify why this does not work?

Comment: Yes,the data is very large so i can't edit every state.

Comment: That is promising.Thank u:)